# Function in VB that doesn't have a return type

Tags: vb.net, vb6

I am not much familiar with Visual Basic 6.0 and am not having a VB compiler installed, but I was looking at some VB code for some debugging and saw this:

```
Private Function IsFieldDeleted(oLayoutField As Object)
    Dim oColl As Collection
    Set oColl = GetFieldIdsForField(oLayoutField)

    IsFieldDeleted = (oColl.Count = 0)

    Set oColl = Nothing
End Function
```

In other functions I see they define the return type with an "As" for example "As Boolean"  but this one does not have an "As" :D and then how they have used it is like this:

```
  If Not IsFieldDeleted(oRptField.GetUCMRLayoutField) Then
      Call oCollection.Add(oRptField, oRptField.ObjectKeyString)
      Call AddToNewLineSeperatedString(sCaseFldDescMsg, oFld.FieldDescription)
  End If
```

How is this working? Is it just like rewriting it and saying that the function returns an integer and compare the return type to be either 0 or 1? Or are there some other hidden tips in there?

Comment: Bit confused... are you asking for VB.NET or VB6?

Comment: this was in VB 6.0 but I thought the same might be true in VB.net?  But the original code is in VB 6.0

Comment: If you dont declare the return type in VB6 it's implicitly "variant", with variant being a kind of "something" ;)

Comment: @igrimpe :  Is it just like rewriting it and saying that function returns an integer and compare the return type to be either 0 or 1? or there are some other hidden tips in there?

Comment: @user1899082: `rewriting it` ... ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When no type is specified, in VB.NET it assumes `Object` for the return type.  In VB6, it assumes `Variant`.  In VB.NET you can make things much more obvious by turning `Option Strict On`, but I don't believe that option was available in VB6.

The value that is returned, in reality, is still typed as a `Boolean`, but you are viewing the returned value as a `Variant`.  So, to do it "properly", you really ought to cast the return value like this:

```
If Not CBool(IsFieldDeleted(oRptField.GetUCMRLayoutField)) Then
   ....
End If
```

Calling `CBool` casts the value to a `Boolean` instead of a `Variant`.  This is unnecessary, though, since VB will use late-binding to determine the type of the return value is a boolean.

The best thing to do in this case is to change the function to `As Boolean`.  Doing so will not break any existing code since that's all it ever returned anyway.  However, if it's a public member in a DLL, that would break compatibility.

Comment: for VB 6.0 version:  Is it just like rewriting it and saying that function returns an integer and compare the return type to be either 0 or 1? or there are some other hidden tips in there?

Comment: IIRC VB6 had an 'Option Explicit', I'm not sure if it enforced explicit function return types.

Comment: +1 @James [`Option Explicit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266183(v=vs.60).aspx) just means you have to declare your variables in a `Dim` statement. Otherwise you can create implicit variables by just using them in a statement - e.g. a typo! `Option Explicit` doesn't mean you have to give variables a type. You can write `Dim x` and `x` will be a variant. Or you can leave off the function return type, and it will return a variant.

Comment: Yes, `Option Explicit` exists in both VB6 and VB.NET, but `Option Strict`, which would be the useful one in this case, only exists in VB.NET.